# An autoclicker I wrote to claim twitch channel points isn't working properly, I'd like to understand why

Tags: autohotkey

I've used AutoHotKey to write out a program that in theory, should claim the little channel point chests on twitch automatically. However, in practice it just does nothing. I'm a bit of a coding noob so cut me some slack. Below is the code:

```
o:: ; this is a killswitch in case anything goes wrong
{
exitapp
} 

p::
while (true)
{
    PixelGetColor, color, 1680, 1060 ; finds the color of a pixel that the chest appears on
    if (color = 8FFFD2) ; if the color of that pixel is the color of the chest when it is highlighted
    {
        Click, 1700, 1060 ; click on where the chest appears
    }
}
```

I tried running this while a chest was there and the code did nothing, I made sure that my mouse was highlighting it too. I also understand that BTTV can claim chests automatically, this is just a little project I'm doing for fun.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is have a line of code to move the mouse to the co-ordinates, and then another line to click.

Try this, it should work:

```
o:: ; this is a killswitch in case anything goes wrong
{
exitapp
} 

p::
while (true)
{
    PixelGetColor, color, 1680, 1060 ; finds the color of a pixel that the chest appears on
    if (color = 8FFFD2) ; if the color of that pixel is the color of the chest when it is highlighted
    {
        Mousemove, 1700, 1060
        click   ; click on where the chest appears
    }
}
```